# Is there a way to move components between components using a swiper in Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, swiper.js, ionic5

Below is an example site.
https://swiperjs.com/demos/020-navigation/core.html

Is it possible to create a slide from a different component.html other than the slide format that works on the same component.html?

For example, slide1 is a.component.html and slide2 is b.component.html.

If not, is it possible to add a side-flip animation in Ionic to move it to another component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible, you have to have ng-templates (or images, or whatever) in the same component.

As for your second question, about the side-flip, you mean transitions?

Here's a nice guide about flip transition (and not only): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4axQp0wfMtU&ab_channel=SimonGrimm

Answer (score -1):

well, You can create slides using the, so to say, ng-app (element bootstraped by angular to be the entry point of the particular angular app (see micro frontends in a way) inside a slide of the swiper :[image]

(check the sample repo and html structure of the app : https://ngx-dummy.github.io/accordion-simple/ )

Answer (score -1):

You can slide between two or more components.

1. Create a page and put your slider inside your page html.
2. Then create a component for each slide.
3. Inside each slide, call your components as thus:

https://pastebin.com/92bNQwXt

```
<slide1></slide1>
```

then you need to listen when the user slides from one slider to another and toggle the booleans showapp1 / showapp2 accordingly.